# Play framework Twitter4J library

Tags: java, playframework, twitter4j

I tried to use the Twitter4J library with the Play! framework using the following dependency in dependencies.yml:

```
require:
    - org.twitter4j -> twitter4j-core [2.2,)
```

After that I let Play! framework resolve the dependencies using the following command:

```
play dependencies --sync
```

Play! framework tells me that some dependencies have been evicted:

```
slf4j-api 1.5.8 is overriden by slf4j-api 1.6.1
```

That being a higher version of the slf4j-api I tried to run the application:

```
play run
```

But unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
16:19:47,208 ERROR ~ Oops. Error in Logger !
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at play.Logger.trace(Logger.java:200)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:221)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
```

Does anyone recognize this problem / know how I can solve or work around this dependency issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure the issue is on slf4j. *Trace* method was added to Log4J 1.2.12. Most likely some dependency on your project is adding an old Log4J in the classpath that's older than that version and lacks the *trace* method.

Check the jars in your lib folder, as well as all your dependencies.

Comment: The Play! framework has a dependency for log4j version 1.2.15.
I tried to force version 1.2.15:
`- log4j 1.2.15: force: true`
Play! framework notifies me that the log4j version is overridden:
`log4j 1.2.9 is overriden by log4j 1.2.15`
But I still get the same error messages about the "Logger.trace" method when trying to run the application.

Comment: @Jan check who is adding that 1.2.9 dependency, that's the source of problems, and remove that module or update it to a newer version

Comment: I figured out that the dependency is set by twitter4j-core 2.2.5, see [twitter4j-core-2.2.5.pom](http://twitter4j.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.2.5/twitter4j-core-2.2.5.pom)

Comment: Problem solved: the solution is forcing log4j version 1.2.15 just like I did before but I forgot to clear the /tmp folder with `play clean`. Thanks, Pere!

Answer (score 0):

One solution maybe is forcibly to use a particular version of a necessary library. For your case it looks like:

```
- slf4j-api 1.5.8:
    force: true
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, I still get the same error messages.